# SQL with multiple SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Hi I have a bit of a problem with my SQL. My problem is when I filter the dates of my data, my SQL statement only returns 2 records which was the employee_id of the user.

This is the original statement of my working code that I have in filtering dates:

```
SELECT * FROM `rmguidef_prs`.`payment_report` WHERE DATE(`Report_Timestamp`) = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)  AND Employee_ID IN (
                               SELECT T1.Employee_ID from `rmguidef_prs`.`employee` T1
                               WHERE T1.Supervisor_ID = '".$id."')
                               OR Employee_ID = '".$id."'
```

This is the modified statement that I need the filters: (its working ok)

```
 SELECT * FROM `report` WHERE Employee_ID IN (
                               SELECT T1.Employee_ID from `employee` T1
                               WHERE T1.Supervisor_ID = '".$id."')
                               OR Employee_ID IN (
                               SELECT T2.Manager_ID from `branches` T2
                               WHERE T2.Manager_ID = '".$id."')
                               OR Employee_ID = '".$id."'
```

But when I add this: `DATE(`Timestamp`) = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)` in the statement to filter the date the only records shown are coming from this: `OR Employee_ID = '".$id."'`

```
SELECT * FROM `report` WHERE DATE(`Timestamp`) = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR) AND Employee_ID IN (
                           SELECT T1.Employee_ID from `employee` T1
                           WHERE T1.Supervisor_ID = '".$id."')
                           OR Employee_ID IN (
                           SELECT T2.Manager_ID from `branches` T2
                           WHERE T2.Manager_ID = '".$id."')
                           OR Employee_ID = '".$id."'
```

I want my modified SQL statement to be filtered by today's date, week, month, and past 3 months. I already have to code for those filters but I cannot figure out how to add those to my statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add parenthesis to group criteria:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `report` 
WHERE DATE(`Timestamp`) = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR) 
  AND (   Employee_ID IN (SELECT T1.Employee_ID 
                          FROM `employee` T1
                          WHERE T1.Supervisor_ID = '".$id."'
                          )
       OR Employee_ID IN (SELECT T2.Manager_ID 
                          FROM `branches` T2
                          WHERE T2.Manager_ID = '".$id."'
                          )
       OR Employee_ID = '".$id."'
      )
```

`AND` takes precedence over `OR`, so your date criteria was only being considered for the first of the three `Employee_ID` criteria.

Edit:  After re-reading your question I'm not entirely sure if the above is what you're after, your date criteria would only return records with tomorrow's date, which probably doesn't exist in the `Timestamp` field, so that's probably the real problem.

Comment: Oh! Its okay because the time is aligned with the server time which is advanced by 1 day. I'll see if this works.